# Twitter Spring Integration - query as payload

Tags: twitter, spring-integration, spring-social

Can I use Twitter Spring Integration as a gateway (or even splitter) instead of a polling consumer? The idea will be to use the payload as a query so I can do multiple twitter custom searches. That payload will come from another chain.

One way will be to use the http outbound gateway, but I will not go into this, because then I will have to implement the entire Twitter API (authentication - twitter template, tweet duplication - metadata store).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper Spring Integration endpoint for that would be a `<si-twitter:outbound-gateway/>` for a request/response scenario; but we don't currently have that; feel free to open a new feature [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) for that.

However, under the covers, we use a `TwitterTemplate`; you can invoke it directly; something like...

```
TwitterTemplate tt = new TwitterTemplate(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken,  accessTokenSecret);
SearchParameters searchParameters = new SearchParameters(query).count(20).sinceId(sinceId);
SearchResults results = tt.searchOperations().search(searchParameters);
```

Comment: If I created such a `TwitterSearchMessageHandler` what will be the correct way to configure it in XML?

Comment: Just define it as a `<bean/>` and invoke it from a `<service-activator input-channel="foo" output-channel="bar" ref="mySearcher" method="search" />`.